# pycurl nosignal & timeout <= 999ms

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

```
import pycurl

pycurl.version
# libcurl/7.29.0 GnuTLS/2.12.23 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT_MS, 1000)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.com/')
c.perform()
# ok

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.com/')
c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT_MS, 999)
c.perform()
# pycurl.error: (28, '')

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.com/')
c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT_MS, 999)
c.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)
c.perform()
# ok again
```

Can someone explain why the timeout less than 1 second failed and nosignal make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to [libcurl API](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_share_setopt.html), `timeout_ms` < 1000 is not allowed when using standard name resolver.

> CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS
>
> An alternative to CURLOPT_TIMEOUT but takes number of milliseconds
>   instead. If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver,
>   that portion of the transfer will still use full-second resolution for
>   timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is because some library calls that CURL does, like for example DNS lookups, do not support timeouts. Therefore, the only way to interrupt them is by setting up a signal.

Comment: I saw some reference that says the curl just ignore the timeout when timeout < 1s. I'll check it later.

Comment: I just tried using curl with TIMEOUT_MS == 500 and it correctly timed out after 500ms.

Comment: which name resolver do you use, the system-standard / c-ares / threaded? Can you post your code in gist if you use system-standard? Reference added, btw.